# Making non square image render as square image without stretching

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, imagick

I have a PHP function that uses Imagick. I am trying to pull a non-square image from a URL and size it up to 500x500px where it doesn't stretch but fits inside this area. Additionally, I am using the Laravel framework and this function is in a controller that is rendered via route.

```
function myFunction()
{
function createGrid()
{
    $placeholder = "https://placeholdit.imgix.net/~text?txtsize=33&txt=&w=500&h=500";
    $im = new imagick("http://www.masters.com/images/pics/large/h_2015041243595.jpg");
    $image = $im->resizeImage(500, 500, 0, 0, true);
    // $target = new Imagick($placeholder);
    // $target->setImageVirtualPixelMethod(Imagick::VIRTUALPIXELMETHOD_TRANSPARENT);
    // $target->compositeImage($image, imagick::COMPOSITE_COPY, 0, 0);
    header("Content-Type: image/png");
    echo $image->getImageBlob();
}
}
```

I am getting an it rendered as:

[image]

How is $Image not an instance of imagick when it's defined as:

```
$im->resizeImage(500, 500, 0, 0, true);
```

What am I doing wrong and how do I fix it?

Comment: Consider using `intervention/image` (it has nice Laravel integration) and the [`crop` function](http://image.intervention.io/api/crop).

Comment: I'll take a look, but I would actually prefer it to fit within a white space.

Comment: For that, http://image.intervention.io/api/resize, http://image.intervention.io/api/canvas, and use http://image.intervention.io/api/insert to add the resized image to the white canvas.

Answer (score 0):

Alternative is cropping the image.

For Imagick this function: http://php.net/manual/en/imagick.cropimage.php

> Imagick::cropImage — Extracts a region of the image

Steps:

- Resize to format so width and height are minimal 500px
- Crop with size of 500px

Comment: Id like it where the image would show the entire image but fit inside a white background.